# Extracting I frame in frame fraction range with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to extract all the I frames, and then arrange the I frames according to all frame index. 
For example. There are 2997 frames in a video, and 200 I frames. I want to arrange the I frame in (1-300) into a folder. and I frames in (301-2997) to another folder.

I know one solution that extract the I frames according to time range with `-ss -t` options. **But some of my videos' frame rate is not integral. so sometimes it's not accurate depend on the time.**

So can I  extract the I frames according to frame range(maybe called fraction of frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf select='eq(pict_type,I)*between(n,0,300)' -vsync 0 i%03d.png
```

This will extract all I-frames from frame #0 to frame #300

Comment: One more question. I need to remember the offset of the I frame . like in (301-2997) I want the image id is not start from 0